# Prevent Account Creation for loggedIn Users Meteorjs

Tags: meteor

How to prevent loggedIn users in creating Account in meteor such as calling `Accounts.createUser` when they are logged in?
Can I pass `Meteor.userId()` when `Accounts.createUser` is called to detect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Accounts.onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser) to abort account creation, add fields, etc.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    if (Meteor.userId())
      throw new Meteor.Error(400, 'Already logged in!');

    return user;
  });
}
```